# Meu programa feito em C++ fica em loop infinito, como corrigir?

Tags: c++, lógica

Meu programa pula direto para o final. Nem entra para ler.

Segue código:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {

int i= 0;
string nome;
for(i=0;i>=10;++i) {
     cin>>nome;
     cout<<nome<<endl;
}

}
```

Não consigo achar o erro.

Comment: Você quer quantos nomes?

Comment: 10 nomes. a resposta já foi respondida

Comment: Então a resposta que você aceitou está errada, vou responder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom amigo, pelo que eu vejo, a sua condição no for nunca será verdadeira e entrará no laço.

Por causa do `for(i=0;i>=10;++i)` ela nem entra, por que `i = 0` e você pergunta i é maior ou igual a 10, então essa condição nunca será verdadeira e nem entrará no laço

Você pode mudar por `for(i=0;i<=10;++i)` e assim irá funcionar devidamente.

Comment: Leia o ciclo `for` do seguinte jeito que é capaz de te ajudar amigo.  O `i`é igual a zero (`i=0`) e enquanto `i`  for menor ou igual a 10 (`i<=10`) adicione/incremente a variável `i` (`++i`)

Answer (score 8):

O operador usado está errado, precisa ser um `<`( menor que). Se você começa do 0 e vai até o 10, e vai incrementando não pode verificar se o número é maior que um determinado valor para determinar se vai continuar. Talvez a confusão seja porque não entendeu bem como funciona a condição no `for`, ali tem que ser verdadeiro para continuar executando, portanto quando for falso ele encerra o laço de repetição. O correto é verificar se o número ainda é menor que o valor alvo desejado que é 10.

Aí pode se perguntar porque deve ser apenas "menor que" e não "menor ou igual a". Porque você começou do 0, e está certo em começar deste número, não que faça tanta diferença, o importante é que ele execute 10 vezes, porque esse é o enunciado do problema, então pode começar do número que quiser e ir até o número adequando para isto, mas convencionou-se começar do 0, então a condição é verdadeira até o número 9, já que o 0 conta também. Por isso o sinal deve ser apenas menor, quando ele for igual, ou sejam chegou no 10, ele deve ser falso, porque começando do 0 o número 10 é o décimo primeiro, um a mais do que deseja. Por isso o use de `<=` está errado e a resposta aceita e votada está errada.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        string nome;
        cin >> nome;
        cout << nome << endl;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/mJVGuQ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pjgvppno-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/Loop.cpp).

Como curiosidade poderia fazer isto:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
```

Aí o `<=` estaria correto porque começou do 1, mas não é assim que programadores fazem, sair do padrão cria dificuldades de entendimento. Escrevemos códigos para todos entenderem e assim é melhor seguir os padrões já adotados.

Answer (score 0):

Do jeito que está, sua função não vai entrar no laço pois a variável 'i' inicia com valor 0 e nunca vai atender à sua condição de ser maior ou igual a 10.

```
for(i=0;i>=10;++i)
```

Portanto, na verdade seu código não está em "loop infinito", ele simplesmente não entra no 'for' e não faz nada.

Answer (score 0):

O seu operador está com os sinais errados, altere a linha:

```
for(i=0;i>=10;++i) {
```

Para:

```
for(i=0;i<10;++i) {
```